Software language specification: null VS empty objects.
I have noticed that in software language specifications, there is pretty much always a NULL element and I am wondering if it is strictly necessary and how it maps to algebraic structures, given that one could consider the empty element as "zero" element.
In-fact, if we consider the (monoid?) of dictionaries, then the empty dictionary is unique and it holds a + {} = {} + a = a, being a a dictionary and + the merging operation; if we take lists, the empty list is unique and it holds b + [] = [] + b = b, being b a list and + the list concatenation operation.
Hence, I am wondering if that NULL is actually necessary, given that using an empty element alone seems to provide a simple, yet strong algebraic structure that constitutes a solid foundation for building up a language specification. The only use-case I can think for the NULL object is for checking the existence of an object and nothing more.
In general, when dealing with Computer Science, I would feel safer if we comply as much as possible with mathematics.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_pointer#:~:text=Programs%20routinely%20use%20null%20pointers,value%20in%20an%20option%20type.

When collecting data, it is quite common to run into situations where you have a list for which empty is a possible known value, but also in some cases, you do not know anything about the list contents. If the language did not provide a null pointer for the case when no information is available, the user would have to introduce some additional flag to indicate that the list is not provided, instead of being known to be empty. This makes your language less flexible, and in general harder to code.
